# Edit Page PHP for Mysql Data

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I'm stucked. I have some pages to edit fields on my database. I can see the tasks and i want to edit them by clicking in "edit" button and redirects to a page where will be displayed the info about that task using the "Nome"(Name), since its unique, but i can't manage how to transfer the name from one page to another.

The code is:

eventos.tarefas.php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width=5%>" . $row[Nome] . "</td>";
  (...)
  echo "<td width=10%>" . $row['Evento'] . "</td>";

  echo ("<td><a href=\"editar_tarefa.php?Nome=$row[Nome]\">Editar</a></td></tr>");  //I'm stuck in this line

  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

editar_tarefa.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tarefas WHERE Nome= '$Nome'");

echo $Nome;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>

<table width="744" height="697">

<tr> 
    <td width="188" height="10"><p style="font-size:30px; font-family:verdana;">ID</p></td>
            <td>
        <input type="text" readonly name="ID" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[ID]"?>" style="width: 400px; height:30px; font-size:150%;background-color:#EEE9E9">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 

(...) and so on...
```

I usually use POST to show the data on database, but i want this to be different.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `$_GET['Nome']` to get the value of the URL parameter. You'd need to assign it to a variable (`$Nome`) before you make your query, obviously

Comment: Thanks!! Worked like a charm! :D

Comment: Happy to help. I've put it as an answer if you'd like to accept ;)

Comment: I'll do it asap. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you noticed how SO's syntax highlighing is making your `Nome` in `$row[Nome]` appear in light blue? It means "someting". ;-) @LuísAssunção - use quotes inside `$row['Nome']`

Comment: My Bad. I had the quotes but while testing i removed them.. xD Thanks @Fred -ii-

Comment: You're welcome, glad to see a solution was found; cheers @LuísAssunção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_GET['Nome']` to get the value of the URL parameter. You'd need to assign it to a variable (`$Nome`) before you make your query, obviously

As you are making a query with user-editable data, you should look into using prepared statements for security.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['name']=$row[Nome];  // $_SESSION['name'] will carry your data until session end
?>
```

On another page

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$nome=$_SESSION['name'];
?>
```

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I use the session to retrieve info too, the tasks that a user have. But in this case, it's not the user "name", but the task "name". @ElendilTheTall helped me out. Thanks you too. :)